# Using worker identity with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I have 2 docker imags with gcloud sdk and my entrypoint script performs some checks using gcloud, like following

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe $GCP_SUB_NAME --quiet
result="$?"

if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Subscription not found, exited with non-zero status $result"
    exit $result
fi
```

I am running these in gke...

I have a different GCP Service Account for each docker image which is connected to GKE Service Account using workload-identity.

My problem is that both deployments don't succeed at the same time. The one which runs first succeeds and other fails with following error. Something to do with the gke/GCP credentials.

I get following error

```
    gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe local-test-v1 --quiet
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.describe) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

If you have already logged in with a different account:

    $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Even if I make following changes I don't get it through

```
gcloud config set account sa@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe $GCP_SUB_NAME --quiet
    result="$?"
    
    if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Subscription not found, exited with non-zero status $result"
        exit $result
    fi
```

Error I get now

```
gcloud config set account sa@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Updated property [core/account].
+ gcloud pubsub subscriptions describe local-test-v1 --quiet
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.describe) Your current active account [sa@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com] does not have any valid credentials
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials.

For service account, please activate it first:

  $ gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT
```

I don't wanna use the GCP client libraries as I want to keep it light weight so either gcloud r curl r the best option.

Can I use gcloud in GKE without the key file?

Can I call googleapis via curl without passing bearer token or how shall I get that in the docker container?

Any ideas... Thanks...

Note#1: workload identity

```
resource "google_service_account_iam_member" "workload_identity_iam" {
  
member = "serviceAccount:${var.gcp_project}.svc.id.goog[${var.kubernetes_namespace}/${var.kubernetes_service_account_name}]"
   
role   = "roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser"    

service_account_id = google_service_account.sa.name    

depends_on = [google_project_iam_member.pubsub_subscriber_iam, google_project_iam_member.bucket_object_admin_iam]  }
```

Note#2: GKE SAs

```
Name:                sa1
Namespace:           some-namespace
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: sa1@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   sa1-token-shj9w
Tokens:              sa1-token-shj9w
Events:              <none>

Name:                sa2  
Namespace:           some-namespace 
Labels:              <none> 
Annotations:         iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: sa2@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
Image pull secrets:            <none>
Mountable secrets:   sa2-token-dkhdl 
Tokens:              sa2-token-dkhdl 
Events:              <none>
```

Note#3: job template for container

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: some-namespace
  name: check
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: check-0.1.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: check
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: check
    app: check
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.1.0"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
        helm.sh/hook: pre-install,pre-upgrade
        helm.sh/hook-weight: "-4"
spec:
  backoffLimit: 1
  completions: 1
  parallelism: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: check
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: check
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: check
        app: check
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      serviceAccountName: sa1
      securityContext:
        {}
      containers:
        - name: check
          securityContext:
            {}
          image: "eu.gcr.io/some-project/check:500c4166"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          env:
            # Define the environment variable
            - name: GCP_PROJECT_ID
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: check
                  key: gcpProjectID
            - name: GCP_SUB
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: check
                  key: gcpSubscriptionName
            - name: GCP_BUCKET
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:         
                  name: check
                  key: gcpBucket
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 128Mi
```

Docker image:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

COPY /checks/pre/ /checks/pre/
ENV HOME /checks/pre/
# Install needed packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends curl \
    iputils-ping \
    tar \
    jq \
    python \
    ca-certificates \
    && mkdir -p /usr/local/gcloud && cd /usr/local/gcloud \
    && curl -o google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -L -O https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
    && tar -xzf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
    && rm -f google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz \
    && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --quiet \
    && mkdir -p /.config/gcloud && chmod 775 -R /checks/pre /.config/gcloud \
    && apt-get autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PATH $PATH:/usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin

WORKDIR /checks/pre

USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT [ "/checks/pre/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Comment: Can you share your yaml files (for the pods)? Can you also perform a `kubectl get serviceaccount` and share the result? Can you detail how did you configure the workload identity on your cluster? (I tested on my side, I had no issue when I used 1 ksa per pod, each identity is respected)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere when m running code that uses GCP client libraries everything is fine... I am facing issue when m using gcloud sdk in a docker image... Have u tested using gcloud sdk in the docker image? I will update the post to include workload-identity and SA details...

Comment: I tested with this command like `kubectl run -it 
  --image google/cloud-sdk:slim 
  --serviceaccount ksa-name 
  --namespace default 
  workload-identity-test` (from [there](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity))

Comment: Added terraform code that m using 4 workload-identity @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere have added the o/p of kubectl describe sa, kubectl get sa gives me 3 sa's default, sa1 & sa2

Comment: Also the problem occurs when any gcloud cmd in the container.. another small detail... My container runs as a job

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere job template updated

Comment: Add the `serviceAccount: sa2` value to your pod spec. You never mentioned the service account to use in your pod

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere seems like they was some issue in copy paste and the template got truncated... I have updated the template and it has a service account

Comment: Your indentation is broken. In addition, it seems to be the Batch job status that you extract not your batch job creation. Can you share how did you create your batch job?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere sorry for the incorrect format working on phone... Have updated the question with the correct template

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere another piece of info that could b of important... M deploying the images via diff shells so m doing gcloud container clusters get-credentials for each deployment...

Comment: Can you try to change `serviceAccountName: sa1` by `serviceAccount: sa1`?

Comment: Have you enabled pub/sub scope when you created the GKE cluster? How about your RBAC role to service account?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have added my docker image code as well , could b an issue with that? I will check by replacing serviceaccount keyword

Comment: @KoopaKiller PubSub scope is disabled but I don't think it has anything 2 do with it as it works sometimes but not always... I will check the RBAC

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere u sure ServiceAccount is a valid option... I can't find any reference to it

Comment: @KoopaKiller I don't c any RBAC associated to the SA... Any specific cmd that u want me to run

Comment: @NikhilGupta, my bad, forget this!

Comment: So, you didn't binding any role to your `sa1` user? So i think it's is the reason, because you create a user that there are any permissions. You can use the command `kubectl get clusterrolebinding` to verify all role bindings in your cluster. You can also user [`kubectl auth can-i`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access) to test if your user has permissions to execute a specific command.

Comment: @KoopaKiller sa1 has following GCP roles Pub/Sub Publisher
Pub/Sub Subscriber, Storage Object Admin, Viewer along with roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser I don't think it's an issue with the SA rather gke cluster is not able to refresh the token association with the user... If I use google cloud client libraries instead of gcloud then every thing seems to be working

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I believe it's some issue with the custom gcloud docker image running in the cluster

Comment: Did you tested a dummy container with gcloud only? [Here](https://github.com/MrKoopaKiller/docker-gcloud-kubectl) there is a container with gcloud and kubectl you can test. PLease let me know the result.

Comment: @KoopaKiller sadly I did not manage to solve it and had to switch gcloud with cloud SDK python library which works... Had an interesting observation that gke sometime fails to generate access token to validate against iam

Comment: Now my very first deployment fails after creating the cluster no matter how long I wait to deploy after creating the cluster.